# Can't see predefined values section on object-specific quick action

Tags: lightning-quickaction

I've created quick action with Lightning Component content source and I wanted to add predefined values for the action. However, I can't see "Predefined Values" section. Do somebody know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set predefined value only for Creating Object-Specific Quick Actions in salesforce. It means you should select an action type as **"create a record"**,  While you are going for action having the source as Lightning Component you can not do it.

If you are creating a record or editing it, You can modify your lightning component accordingly to set the predefined values.